# Monit: delay the next monitor cycle after a service test action condition has been met

Tags: apache, monit

When my server gets into high load, a graceful restart of Apache seems to bring things back under control. So I set up monit, with this configuration:

```
set daemon 10
check system localhost
      if loadavg (1min) > 5 then exec "/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful"
```

So every 10 seconds, I poll the server load, and when it gets above 5, I gracefully restart Apache. However, that temporarily raises the load, so we get into a death spiral. What I want is for it to notice after 10 seconds that the load is 5 or more, and gracefully restart Apache, then *wait* for 5 minutes or so before checking that particular metric again.

Is there a way to do this with monit?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely within monit, but it's close enough

```
set daemon 10
check system localhost
  if loadavg (1min) > 5 then unmonitor
  if loadavg (1min) > 5 then exec "/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful"
  if loadavg (1min) > 5 then exec "python /scripts/remonitor.py"
```

Then you have a python script, like so:

```
import time, os

time.sleep(5*60)
os.system("monit monitor system")
```

So this will:
1. unmonitor "system" when it reaches too much load, to prevent the death spiral
2. restart apache gracefully
3. start the script that will re-monitor the "system" in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
set daemon 10

set limits { programtimeout: 300 seconds }

check system localhost
   if loadavg (1min) > 5 then exec "/bin/sh -c '/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful && sleep 5m'"
```

or even

```
set daemon 10

check system localhost
   start program = "/bin/sh -c '/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful && sleep 5m'" with timeout 330 seconds
   if loadavg (1min) > 5 then start
```

I.e., just add the `sleep 5m` shell command after the command to restart Apache and add the appropriate timeout to the monitrc.